# Check if vector B exists as a subsequence in a list of vectors A

Tags: arrays, matrix, pytorch, substring, match

I  have an int pytorch vector tensor B,  and a list of int pytorch vector tensors A. I want to find all vector elements and its indexes of A that contain B.

Note: B should appear completely and continually  in A's elements.

Example:

```
input:
B = [1,2]
A = [
        [0,1,2],
        [1,0,2],
        [1,2],
    ]
output:
0 1 # 0-th element of A and index 1
2 0 # 2-th element of A and index 0
```

I have investigated the sub-string matching methods such as Boyer-Moore and KMP. However, I am wondering if any tensor-calculating methods could address this problem, and whether the tensor-calculating methods could be more efficient.

Comment: my two cents is you're probably better off with substring methods. tensor methods work best with broadcasting and parallel processing. but for this problem, that would mean checking every substring in A against B, doing the exhaustive search. my guess is substring methods would be much faster for this problem.

Comment: @Karl Thanks for your reply. I did solve the problem using string approaches. I first convert the int tensors into strings and apply Python find() function to find the match position. This approach not elegant but still efficient.